# serverless-s3-sync just specifc folders to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I am currently using the [`serverless-s3-sync`](https://github.com/k1LoW/serverless-s3-sync) plugin for syncing my local directory into an S3 Bucket.

My code in the `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```
custom:
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: mydestintationBucket
      localDir: .
      acl: public-read
```

My problem is I don't want to sync the whole directory to the S3 bucket. Is there a way to define just specific folders/files for sync to S3, or is there a better/other way to do so (e.g. another plugin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current version [1.10.6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-s3-sync) you can't link files explicitely. You can however add (multiple) directories.

```
custom:
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: mydestintationBucket
      prefix: folderA
      localDir: ./folderA
    - bucketName: mydestintationBucket
      prefix: folderB
      localDir: ./folderB
```

This will ignore all the files from `folderC` or the other files from `.`.

Comment: Will `deleteRemoved: true` conflict here?